# React ag-grid - wait for the 'end' of ' grid resize' event and only then perform an action

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

In ag-grid, we have 'onGridSizeChanged' events which is calling when we resizing the window. But it's calling many time while resizing the window. I want to perform an action only after resizing end.

Do we have any events to use on resizing end?

If not, please guide me how to perform action after resizing end in ag-grid?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried below?

`columnResized`

It's in the 'Columns' section here:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/